# How to vectorize signal and parameter?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a subsystem in Simulink  with mask underneath. There are all sorts of control and calculation inside this subsystem. Now I have to duplicate this subsystem for one hundred thousand times because I need to connect one hundred thousands of this block in series.

What I have tried, I used the commands “add_block” and “add_line” where I can just type it in the Matlab command and the blocks and lines are added automatically.

What I wish to do now is, 
I want to have 100 signals in a single subsystem, so instead of using one hundred thousand subsystem, I will only need one thousand of this subsystem, I understand that this can be done by vectorization.

I have a very limited knowledge on using vectorization feature in Matlab/Simulink. I appreciate if anyone of you could provide me a great reference on how to do this?

What I found here is something like this which I could not link it to my issue above: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

The other thing I found is by "using vectorization for most components. Most components are vectorized if they have a vectorized input signal or if one of their parameter is specified as a vector."

However, I could not find any further information/details, appreciate if anyone of you could give opinion on this? Thanks!

Comment: I would question the "need" to have 100,000 copies of a subsystem inside a model... I'm not sure the model would run...

Comment: Thanks am304, you replied my previous thread, but I was unable to post a long comment there, that's why I created a new post here. Well, that was the objective of having 100k cells, but if I could proceed with 100 cells, that is very useful as well. I just went through this information where it uses for each subsystem to do the task, still I have yet to figure out how it could relate to my problem in depth, forgive my poor ability http://www.mathworks.co.uk/videos/for-each-subsystem-for-vectorizing-algorithms-68939.html